# sql combine row with condition in one table and select maximum revision

Tags: sql

I have a query combine rows as below:

```
UPDATE  SO_DistributionList
SET [Distribution_List_Item]=REPLACE([Distribution_List_Item],' ','|')
SELECT mainID as 'MainID',Revision,reqno as 'Request No',REPLACE
(Units,'|', ' ')  as 'Distribution list item' FROM
(SELECT t1.mainid, t1.revision,t1.reqno,
   Units =REPLACE( 
   (SELECT Distribution_List_Item AS [data()]
       FROM SO_DistributionList] t2
      WHERE t2.mainid = t1.mainid and t2.revision = t1.revision
      ORDER BY Distribution_List_Item
        FOR XML PATH('')
        ), ' ', ';')
  FROM SO_DistributionList t1
  GROUP BY mainID, Revision,reqno)
  t0
```

Result from above query:
[image: Picture: result from above query]

However, I would like to select the maximum revision to display instead of all.

Thank you.

Comment: Please tag your DBMS, `sql` is a standard.

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images (or links to them.)